# How to use gradle-android-test-plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I want to get Robolectric working with Android Studio and am attempting to use [gradle-android-test-plugin][1] after reviewing answers to this [question][2], but am having no luck.

1. I created a brand new Android project and named it MyApp.
2. I followed all the instructions in the "Usage" section of the README.
3. I didn't yet have any code to test in my new project, so I copied the classes (including the `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`) from the

```
gradle-android-test-plugin/example/src/test/java/com/example
```

and the

```
gradle-android-test-plugin/example/src/main/java/com/example
```

directories into corresponding file paths in my new MyApp project.

I've never implemented unit testing for Android before and I don't know what to do next. I successfully ran **`./gradlew install`** in the root directory of the the plugin, but doing the same in the root directory of my new project accomplishes nothing. It throws this complaint:

```
Task 'install' is ambiguous in root project 'MyApp'. Candidates are: 'installDebug', 'installTest'.
```

I'm not at all familiar with Gradle, so short of reading a textbook on Gradle itself, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

If I enter the MyApp directory containing `AndroidManifest.xml` and try the **`../gradlew clean check`** to build and run the tests, I get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testDebug'.
```

Android Studio doesn't seem to be having any issues finding my dependencies. Can someone point me in the direction of running my tests, please? I imagine it's a simple terminal command or something that wasn't mentioned in the plugin's README. Cheers!

edit:

Here is my `build.gradle`. I'm aware it's not structurally identical to that of the example project included with the plugin, but that structure gave me identical errors.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

edit2:
Besides the fact that I was issuing the wrong commands (as indicated in Ravindra's answer), I also failed to realize my version of Gradle was too new (as Jake's comment points out).

Comment: RE: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testDebug'. Gradle 1.7 is not supported yet.

Comment: ... and this is how you make the wrapper use 1.6: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html, then run gradle wrapper (NOT ./gradlew wrapper)

Comment: This issue is [tracked on github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/3) and a fix is going out very soon. By the time you're reading this, it's probably already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no install task but there are two tasks which are prefixed with install. You have to supply the full task name or at least enough for Gradle to figure out which one you are talking about (e.g., installD, iD, or the full thing installDebug will work)

https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/6#issuecomment-22881923

Comment: Is my `build.gradle` not complete then? Thanks to your help, I now understand that `./gradlew install` refers to the `build.gradle` in the root directory of the plugin, but where does "installDebug" come from? 

When I try `gradle testDebug`, I still get the familiar `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testDebug'.`

Answer (score 2):

for list of available tasks run from main project folder

```
gradle tasks
```

for tests

```
gradle tests
```

Comment: If I try `gradle tasks` or `gradle test`, then  I get the following:
`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testDebug'.`

If I try `gradle tests`, then this is what I get:
`Task 'tests' not found in project ':MyApp'. Some candidates are: 'tasks', 'test'.`

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin's code, it seems like you should run `./gradlew test` command for tests to be executed

Comment: Yeah, I saw a mention of this in the plugin's README too. But **`./gradlew test`** from the root directory or **`../gradlew test`** from the directory containing `AndroidManifest.xml` results in:

`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testDebug'.`